# Set FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT for Appearance Settings File Upload

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

In Drupal 7, I have a theme with the following code in theme-settings.php:

```
function greytheme_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, $form_state)
{
    $form["greytheme_home_img"] = array(
        '#type'          => 'managed_file',
        '#title'         => t('Home Page Image'),
        '#description'   => t("Home page image to be used in the ribbon."),
        // fileID (fid) used to display the file later
        '#default_value' => variable_get('greytheme_home_img', ''), 
        '#upload_location' => 'public://homeimg/',
        '#upload_validators' => array(
            'file_validate_extensions' => array("png jpg jpeg gif"),
        ),
    );
}
```

This will allow me to upload and validate an image on the appearance Settings admin screen for this theme.

The file is written to the filesystem as expected. However, the file upload is not marked `FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT` in the database, causing it to be swept away by the cronjob later. How do I "catch" the results of this file upload so that I can set `FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT` and get the `fid` of the `managed_file` object? I have a feeling it has something to do with [system_theme_settings_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.admin.inc/function/system_theme_settings_submit/7) but I am not sure what to override.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add a custom submit handler to the form, you can grab the `fid` from there:

```
function greytheme_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  $form["greytheme_home_img"] = array(
    '#type'          => 'managed_file',
    '#title'         => t('Home Page Image'),
    '#description'   => t("Home page image to be used in the ribbon."),
    // fileID (fid) used to display the file later
    '#default_value' => variable_get('greytheme_home_img', ''), 
    '#upload_location' => 'public://homeimg/',
    '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array("png jpg jpeg gif"),
    ),
  );

  $form['#submit'][] = 'greytheme_system_theme_settings_form_submit';
}

function greytheme_system_theme_settings_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $fid = $form_state['values']['greytheme_home_img'];
  $file = file_load($fid);
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  file_save($file);
}
```

Comment: When I submit theme appearance settings, Drupal doesn't require theme-settings.php before it tries to call `greytheme_system_theme_settings_form_submit()`, resulting in a fatal. Where should I declare `greytheme_system_theme_settings_form_submit()`?

Comment: I'd go with `template.php`, if that doesn't work then you'll probably need to put it in a custom module

Comment: I had to write it in a custom module, as Drupal doesn't seem to load _any_ theme files when doing a theme settings submit. Seems silly that I had to write a module with essentially one function in it, but I got it to work.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but if you want a workaround for the module, read up https://www.drupal.org/node/1862892.  #7 is a working patch for that issue, it will add the relevant fix to system.admin.inc.  #9 also provides code you can add directly to your settings_alter function if you do not want to bother with the patch.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `variable_get('greytheme_home_img', '')`? That didn't work for me, so I used `theme_get_setting('greytheme_home_img')`

Comment: `theme_get_setting()` is what you're *supposed* to use, and it catches the image, but storing it this way doesn't set `FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT`. Instead I wrote a module that's called after submitting the settings form that stores the managed image ID in `greytheme_home_img` using `variable_get()`, `variable_set()`.